# Blank space in MySQL result strings

Tags: java, mysql

Why when I run this code:

```
pst = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * from game");
rs = pst.executeQuery();
while(rs.next()){
    System.out.println("id:"+rs.getString(1));
    System.out.println("firstname: " + rs.getString(2));
    System.out.println("lastname: " + rs.getString(3));
    System.out.println("--------------------------------------");
}
```

The output is (I don't know why I can not copy txt here, so I have used an image):

[image]

My problem is the blank space.

Comment: The field in database have black space or are stored well?

Comment: Data in your table has space.

Comment: Check database like comments said. But as a temp solution you could use `.replaceAll("\\s+","")` to remove the space

Comment: No space http://i.gyazo.com/894b03e6b07b45b7bcd2e8aac10e51ce.png

Comment: @gudthing Doesn't work :\

Comment: Try Adding  One more row in your database with String as values  not numbers and post the complete result

Comment: Can you show the definition of your `game` table, please?

Answer (score 0):

Temp solution is you can use Replace(colname , ' ' , '') in your sql query

Comment: If i have a 2 words with a space they will delete it

Answer (score 0):

This may (or may not) be a mismatch between the character set of your data and the character set you're using in Java.  Try issuing this MySQL command right after you connect your Java program to MySQL:

```
 SET character_set_results = utf8;
```

If that doesn't work, you might try

```
 SET character_set_results = latin1;
```

(I am guessing. But this smells like a character set issue to me.)

Comment: Yes, i have just solved by changing the charset.
But thank you :)